# Highcharts issue when start index is less than 0

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts chart thats series is bound to an array (lets say 900 int value array). The way I would like to display this is for the first number on the xAxis to be -450 and the last number to be positive 450 with zero in the center.
I was able to achieve this by settings the min and max of the xAxis, but when the chart renders the first value (from the array) does not render where I would expect, it starts at 0 and ignores what come before it.
Also, as you can see the xAxis is displaying the bear minimum of values, I would like it to have a smaller step, but dont see anything in the api for that either

[image]

I am kinda scratching my head on this one and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
 var t = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: chart,
                        spacingTop: 0,
                        animation: false,
                        width: 420,
                        height: 280
                    },
                    credits: { enabled: false },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    exporting: { enabled: false },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'left',
                        x: 40,
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        y: 20,
                        floating: true,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
                    },
                    title: { text: "Profile X" },
                    xAxis: [{
                        min: 0 - arr[0].length / 2,
                        max: arr[0].length / 2,
                        ordinal: false
                    }],
                    yAxis: [{
                            labels: { style: { color: set1Color } },
                            title: { enabled: false, text: null },
                            min: min,max: max
                    },
                        {
                            labels: { enabled: false },
                            title: { enabled: false, text: null }
                        },
                        {
                            opposite: true,
                            labels: { style: { color: diffColor } },
                            title: { enabled: false, text: null },
                            min: minD, max: maxD
                        }],
                    series: [{
                            name: "Expected",
                            color: set1Color,
                            type: "line",
                            data: arr[0]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Delivered",
                            color: set2Color,
                            type: "line",
                            data: arr[1],
                            yAxis: 1
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Difference",
                            color: diffColor,
                            type: "line",
                            data: arr[2],
                            yAxis: 2
                        }]
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here we go, docs:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data
- http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series#1

this is how it works when you set data in format: `[val, val, val]`. First value will get x=0;, second x=1 etc.

If you want to start from 450, then set `series.pointStart = -450`, like this:

```
                series: [{
                        name: "Expected",
                        color: set1Color,
                        type: "line",
                        data: arr[0], 
                        pointStart: -450
                    }, ... ]
```

Comment: Your the man,  for some reason that property does not exist in their API docs http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

Comment: It's under plotOptions, since you can set that for all series once: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart